# Merging two Lists into object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two lists with different properties. List A has Name, Date. List B has three address details for an User with properties Surname, Mobile number, EMail etc. Can i Combine these two list into a single object of type UserDetails where the Model for USerDEtails inlcude all the above properties in both list A and List B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!

Note, this example assumes that the record count for *both* lists are the same and that record 0 in list 1, corresponds to record 0 in list 2.

Using a simple example:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public DateTime Date {get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Surname {get; set;} 
    public string Mobile {get; set; }
}

public class Combined
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public DateTime Date {get; set; }
    public string Surname {get; set;} 
    public string Mobile {get; set; }
}


List<A> list1 = /*... */;
List<B> list2 = /*... */;
List<Combined> combined = new List<Combined>(list1.Count + list2.Count);
for(int c = 0; c < list1.Count; ++ c)
{
    combined.Add(new Combined()
    {
        Name = list1[c].Name,
        Date = list1[c].Date,
        Surname = list2[c].Surname,
        Mobile = list2[c].Mobile
    });
}
```